# Regex to match URL not surrounded by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
/(?!")(https?:\/\/\S*\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|svg|webp)(\?([\w=&_%\-]*))?)(?!")/gi
```

to match image urls like `http://example.com/image.png`, but don't match if the url is surrounded by quotes `"`, for example `<a href="http://example.com/image.png"></a>` should not match.

---

Now I have a special case:

```
<a href="https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>
```

Normally it shouldn't match (because surrounded by quotes), but because the domain name contains `.gif`, it still matches `https://i.gif`.

---

Is it possible to make this regex match `https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif` but  doesn't match `<a href="https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>` (because surrounded by quotes) ?

---

For example:

```
<a href="https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>
-> should NOT match

foo https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif bar
-> should match: https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif

<a href="https://google.com/image.gif"></a>
-> should NOT match

foo https://google.com/image.gif bar
-> should match: https://google.com/image.gif
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML image elements and get their `src`?

Comment: That happens because the `(?!")` is a negative lookahead (that does not do anything meaningful in your regex, you may remove it as it is redundant), while you need a lookbehind, [`(?<!")`](https://regex101.com/r/FLzP9f/2). In older ECMAScript versions, use [`(^|[^"])`](https://regex101.com/r/FLzP9f/1)

Comment: @chŝdk i'm just trying to know if a string contains: a URL or a URL surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first lookahead construct shouldn't be there. Since most browsers don't support lookbehinds yet, you'd better do something like this:

```
"[^"]*"|(https?:\/\/[^\/\s]+\/\S+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|tiff|png|svg|webp))\b
```

This way you have your desired match in first capturing group.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/MQWU9a/3)

Comment: Your regex may overmatch, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MQWU9a/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Feel free to add `\s` within first set of brackets.

Comment: Yes, however, this won't match [`"https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"`](https://regex101.com/r/MQWU9a/4) that is outside `<a>` tag. OP wants to only avoid matching URLs inside `<a>` tags (*but don't match if the url is included in a `<a>` tag*).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mind the title of question.

Comment: Right, now it sounds as in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You shouldn't edit the question and narrow down the issue to `<a>` tags. Do you mean OP wants `<input type="image" src="http://example.com/path/to/image.png" />` to be matched? I don't think so.

Comment: I did not change the question, just made sure the question itself matches the title. Besides, we must edit poor titles if it is clear they are wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I consider `<a>` in question to just be an example. Yet title remains valid.

Comment: An act of clarification should be done only by OP, otherwise we may invalidate other answers.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've added clarifications in the question itself

Comment: @julesbou Current regex works for all provided examples. See it here https://regex101.com/r/MQWU9a/5

Comment: Thanks. It seems like your regex still match `<a href="https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>` but it should not.

Comment: @julesbou You need to use back-references. See colors in regex101. Those in green are your desired URLs. Those are in first capturing group.

Comment: Steps in approaching to select and accept an answer should be taken carefully. With having in mind *who* is answering *what*.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a word boundary match, `\b`, after the file extension:

```
/(?!")(https?:\/\/\S*\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|svg|webp)\b(\?([\w=&_%\-]*))?)(?!")/gi
```

See [Using Special Characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters)

Comment: No, [this won't work in other cases](https://regex101.com/r/FLzP9f/3), with `<a href="https://i.gif-er.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>`, for example.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to add `^` (matches beginning of input) and `$` (matches end of input). I'm sure that something like below would work for you:

```
/^(?!")(https?:\/\/\S*\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|svg|webp)(\?([\w=&_%\-]*))?)(?!")$/gi
```

Comment: Why -1? The orginal question gives 2 samples: `'<a href="https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"></a>'` and `'https://google.com/image.gif'` and my suggestion just matches the second one as requirement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew let's try to run the code by yourself with your own node.js, or some better tool like this https://repl.it/repls/StupidYellowishSupercollider

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  the original question does not include "foo https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif bar", just "https://i.gifer.com/Vs5X.gif"